# Is it possible to give UITableViewCells each a unique ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

To expand, I have a UITableView of two cells, and I want to give each of the cells, when tapped, their own unique view controller (as their functions will be different). I have scoured this website, as well as Google and could not quite find an answer. Here's the set up of my UITableView:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let functions = ["Rule of 72","Future Value", "Simple Interest"]
    

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.functions[indexPath.row]
       return cell
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 3
    }
}
```

Ultimately, the idea is to build an app that allows for the calculation of certain financial and economic equations. These equations will require different inputs and outputs (Rule of 72 will only need one UITextField, whereas Future Value will need four UITextField's).

Comment: Add the function tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) and use this to present a different view controller when a cell is tapped

Comment: showSegue your ViewController in UiTableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a enum confirming to CaseIterable. Also implement the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    enum OptionTypes: CaseIterable {
        case ruleOf72
        case futureValue
        case simpleInterest
        
        var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .ruleOf72: return "Rule of 72"
            case .futureValue: return "Future Value"
            case .simpleInterest: return "Simple Interest"
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let item = OptionTypes.allCases[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.description
        return cell
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return OptionTypes.allCases.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = OptionTypes.allCases[indexPath.row]
        switch item {
        case .ruleOf72:
            navigateToRuleOf72ViewController()
        case .futureValue:
            navigateToFutureValueViewController()
        case .simpleInterest:
            navigateToSimpleInterestViewController()
        }
    }
    
    
    private func navigateToRuleOf72ViewController() {}
    
    private func navigateToFutureValueViewController() {}

    private func navigateToSimpleInterestViewController() {}

}
```